# How does this expression work

Tags: elixir

I am pretty new in elixir and tried following code:

```
iex(19)> [1,2,true,false,true] -- [true, false]
[1, 2, true]
```

Can someone please explain, how this works?

Answer (score 2):

You've subtracted two lists here and the result is the set difference. The 3rd and 4th items were not included in the final result. Is this what you're asking?

```
iex(19)> [1,2,true,false,true] -- [true, false]  # [1,2,_,_,true] is the union
[1, 2, true]
```

Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Christian's excellent answer you might also want to look at the Elixir Kernel Module docs ([here](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/Kernel.html#--/2)). Specifically this:

> Removes the first occurrence of an item on the left for each item on
>   the right.